# ZUUIRevealControler: Issue in size of rearViewContriller's View While running in iPhone(Retina 4Inch)

Tags: ios6, retina-display, iphone-5

I got an issue with ZUUIRevealController.

ISSUE:

While running in iPhone (Retina 4Inch) simulator the height of [rearViewController View] is still

```
frame = (0 0; 320 480)
```

instead of

```
frame = (0 0; 320 568).
```

So the rear view seem to be truncated.

But this issue is not there for frontViewController.

Here is how I added my rearViewController and frontViewController

```
viewCont1 *frontViewController = [[viewCont1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"viewCont1" bundle:nil];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

    viewCont2 *rearViewController = [[viewCont1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewCont1" bundle:nil];

    revealController = [[RevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:navigationController rearViewController:rearViewController];

    revealController.delegate = rearViewController;
```

Any one ever came across such an issue?? 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out. We have to keep both the front and rear VC as navigationController

```
frontVc *frontViewController = [[frontVc alloc]initWithNibName:@"frontVc" bundle:nil];

frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

rearVc *rearViewController = [[rearVc alloc] initWithNibName:@"rearVc" bundle:nil];

rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

revealController = [[RevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:frontNavigationController rearViewController:rearNavigationController];
```